# Implement an IP on Debian to redirect & failover on 2 external IPs

Tags: ip, failover

Hello network & sys gurus,

I would like to use one Debian server inside a cluster to host a 
IP 1 redirecting to IP 2, or if IP 2 is not reachable, redirecting to IP 3. IP 2 and IP 3 are hosted outside of the cluster & are out of my zone of control.

Every other servers inside that cluster would seamlessly connect to IP 1, and the Debian server hosting IP 1 would figure out either IP 2 or IP 3 should be the next hop.

I found many articles about Heartbeat daemon, but it seems like appropriate only when IP 2 & 3's hosts can have the daemon installed, which is not possible in my case.

Would you have any suggestion regarding such scenario ?

Thank you in advance for your help,
Best,
Lucas

Comment: You could have a look at the [Linux Virtual Server Project](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org).

Comment: Perfect, that exactly suits my needs ! Thank you :)

Comment: Great! Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [gf_](https://serverfault.com/users/269679/gf) for suggesting [Linux Virtual Server Project](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/), their Virtual server via NAT is exactly what I needed.

Thanks to all for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

Check out [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) as it describes itself:

> HAProxy is a free, very fast and reliable solution offering high availability, load balancing, and proxying for TCP and HTTP-based applications. It is particularly suited for very high traffic web sites and powers quite a number of the world's most visited ones. Over the years it has become the de-facto standard opensource load balancer, is now shipped with most mainstream Linux distributions, and is often deployed by default in cloud platforms. Since it does not advertise itself, we only know it's used when the admins report it :-)

Lolz, but there you have it.

Install haproxy then you should create one front end pool on IP1 and configure IP2 and IP3 as servers behind it.  It sounds like you can use both at the same time, but it you want something more complicated you can have each of the serving IPs in their own pool and only fail out of the IP2 pool if it is down.  How does haproxy know the IP is down?  When a health check fails.  You will need to find some harmless URL to build into a health check so haproxy can proactively verify that the backend IP's are functional.

Comment: chiks, thanks for your fast answer !
Unfortunately, HAProxy is already dealing with TCP/HTTP, while I need to stay at IP layer. Indeed, many other things than TCP/HTTP will go through IP1 (like SSH & SFTP)

HAProxy at IP level would be great :)

Comment: @Lucas What do you mean by "IP level"? Did you try to use `HAProxy` in `tcp mode`?

Comment: I'm guessing he wants or "needs" UDP or ICMP.